# how to give the id of image in drupal 7 views?

Tags: views

I have a view in drupal 7 and I am displaying node title and node image .
I need to give id for a image.
Now I am getting:

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/drupal-7.36/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/field/image/STF-332.jpg?itok=Kpd_9XUk" width="220" height="220" alt="">
```

But I need Id .Means I need

```
<img typeof="foaf:Image" src="http://localhost/drupal-7.36/sites/default/files/styles/medium/public/field/image/STF-332.jpg?itok=Kpd_9XUk" width="220" height="220" alt="" id="myID">
```

Answer (score 0):

If a unique class is acceptable, you can add a class to a field using built-in features. Under the field settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you need that ID for? If you need it for some java-script processing on the image you can add a `span` with the image id inside it next to the image with the style `display:none`. To do so add the **NID** field *BEFORE* the image in the fields and then check the Rewrite Results and use this code:

[image]

Now you can easily get the image ID by this JS code

```
var nid = $("TheImageSelector").siblings(".image-span").text();
```

But if you have to use the ID you need to use template files. install [Image Link Formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_link_formatter) module to get the image link instead of the image object then build the `<a>` .